# Looking for the title of a sci-fi book about a traveling space carnival/zoo

Tags: story-identification

Trying to find the name of a science fiction book I read in the late 70s. All I remember is that it is about an orphan boy who somehow gets onto a spacecraft that is some kind of traveling circus/zoo...and early in the book the ship for some reason is triggers into high gee acceleration and some animals die...that's all I can remember

Comment: It's a long shot, but maybe you're thinking of Barry B. Longyear's [Circus World Series?](https://www.goodreads.com/series/53706-circus-world)

Comment: Hi,thanks I will check that out.

Comment: Checked it out, I don't believe that is what I was looking for, but again thank you for your time.

Comment: Your description of earth blood sure sounds like it...I will check it out see if I can find it on kindle, thanks a million

Comment: Thanks @MarkDolz, if that turns out to be it, please come back and mark the answer as correct, to help out future searchers (and our reputation scores).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for story - post human galactic civilization](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160257/looking-for-story-post-human-galactic-civilization)

Comment: Duplicate target has formally accepted answer. See OP comment above; this is highly likely match but lacks explicit confirmation.

Answer (score 6):

I think there is a chance you are remembering [Earthblood](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2028) by Keith Laumer and Rosel George Brown.

> an orphan boy who somehow gets onto a spacecraft that is some kind of traveling circus/zoo

The young hero is kidnapped by a travelling interstellar circus owner who sees his ability to perform acrobatics.  The circus owner kills the hero's parents (his father at least) so that matches the orphan part too.

> Early in the book the ship for some reason is triggers into high gee
> acceleration

In Chapter 8 (about 1/3 of the way through the book) the old ship's battle reflex circuits are triggered (by a malfunction?) and it goes into high acceleration.  The circus's Earth elephant, at least, dies because of this, maybe others do too.

> I read in the late 70s.

Written in 1966, but frequently reprinted.  There was a 1979 paperback reprint.

This book is a cracking good read, tainted only by its theme of racial superiority.

[image]

Comment: It's been quite a while since I read it. At the end, doesn't the young hero learn that his alien friends are better people than his blood relatives on Earth?

Comment: It could well be. It's been a long time since I read it as well.  But seeing this question put it in my to-read pile.

Comment: Those who sneer at Gooks (divergent humans) and Geeks (nonhumans) are, in the rosy glow of my memory, consistently hypocritical and/or decadent.