# Looking for story - post human galactic civilization

Tags: story-identification

A story from my [edit - son's] youth, so the description is sort of fragmented.

1. Humans are almost extinct, most that remain are mutated or cross-breeds.
2. Earth's location is forgotten, but main characters find it.
3. Earth surrounded by blockade of derelict ships.
4. Aliens lack the ambition/survival drive of humans - a broken leg might be a fatal injury.
5. Galactic civilization is decaying.

Comment: Welcome to the site! =) This is a good first post, but I wonder if you could add any of the things listed on [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info). The more info like that you provide us, the faster your answers are likely to come :)

Comment: When was your youth? Last year? Last decade? The 15th century? Was it a short story or novel?

Comment: Oops, I should edit this - it's actually my son's youth, so probably 10-15 years ago.

Comment: A winner from Organic Marble - Earthblood is it. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Please click the checkmark by the answer to mark it as correct. It's also a possible (unaccepted) answer to this old question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105673/looking-for-the-title-of-a-sci-fi-book-about-a-traveling-space-carnival-zoo/105680

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may be [Earthblood](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2028) by Keith Laumer and Rosel George Brown

> 1. **Humans are almost extinct, most that remain are mutated or
>    cross-breeds.**

This is the major premise of the book. The hero is an almost-unique pure strain Terran

> 2. **Earth's location is forgotten, but main characters find it.**

In the latter part of the book, the hero and his comrades' search for Terra is successful.

> 3. **Earth surrounded by blockade of derelict ships.**

The alien Niss fleet orbits Terra but is abandoned/filled with dead Niss.

> "I see our dreadnoughts, all in station, orbiting the enemy homeworld.
> But no one answers our signals...."

-- the last surviving Niss

> 4. **Aliens lack the ambition/survival drive of humans - a broken leg might be a fatal injury.**

Sounds familiar, but a quick check did not turn this up

> 5. **Galactic civilization is decaying.**

Again, a major premise of the book.

Comment: Yep, *Earthblood* for sure. Point 4 is early in the story, before Roan joins the circus. His gracyl playmates are left for dead if they break a leg.