# Sci Fi book about the last pure blood Terran

Tags: story-identification

Humans have all but left Terra (Earth) and spread out over outer space.

It starts out with a man and women dis-formed and mutated. They go to a disreputable embryo dealer. And they are told it is the last pure blood Terran.

The child is raised on a planet of dactyl humanoids. When a slave circus comes to town, he sneaks in by climbing a wall. He is caught and made a slave.

There is a giant rock creature and other weird beings. Ultimately he makes his way to Terra, and almost dies there due to a lack of Terran antibodies.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! What you've provided is useful; that said, you may want to check out the answers to [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/), for ideas on additional information you can add to your question. For example: roughly when did you read this book? Any sign of how old the book might have been at that point? Do you recall anything about the book's cover? What language was the book in? Do you know if it was originally written in that language?

Comment: Thank you. Well, I read it in 2016, but in  jail. So the cover was gone.

Comment: But I believe it is any from mid 70's to 80's. The pages were quite yellow brownish paper. It was in English, I believe that is the original language. I can expand further on the book. Just don't want to ruin a future read for anyone.    The guy is the odd friend of a dactyl, pre slave circus.  is treated well on slave ship, makes a love connection and friends, at the end of the slave ship part he can't save his friends from the ships explosion.  when he first gets to Terra, he finds a beautiful park, with life likestatue

Comment: I remember this one. The rock body giant, that is the Terran's friend in the circus has to eventually do battle, and finally mortally wounded by a "dinosaur" type creature. Trying to research the title and author....

Comment: This is [*Earthblood*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2028) by Keith Laumer and Rosel George Brown.

Comment: A version of *Earthblood* was serialized in *If* and is available for free at the Internet Archive in [*If*, April 1966](https://archive.org/details/1966-03_IF) and [*If*, May 1966](https://archive.org/details/1966-05_IF) anf [*If, June 1966](https://archive.org/stream/1966-06_IF#page/n1/mode/2up) and [*If*, July 1966](https://archive.org/details/1966-07_IF).

Comment: See this old question and answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105673/looking-for-the-title-of-a-sci-fi-book-about-a-traveling-space-carnival-zoo

Comment: What you remember as a "dactyl" is an alien being called a "gracyl" if I remember right.

Comment: Yes, that is it. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the answer, but it seems possible the story could be *Earthblood* by Keith Laumer and Rosel George Brown (1966), since the protagonist is a pure blood human named Roan and there is a space circus.  The acrobatic and athletic full blooded human Roan grows up in community on a distant planet full of aliens and mutated humans and eventually becomes part of a circus travelling the stars.  The circus ship is eventually attacked by pure blood human space pirate Harry Dread and Roan goes with Harry to search the universe for more pure blood humans.

Comment: I would have answered but you beat me to it, so please expand this into a real answer. You can use the links provided in my comments above to get the text of the story.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is "Earthblood" by Laumer and Brown